# What are the advantages of using threads in Flask App

Tags: flask, gunicorn, python-multithreading

I have a Flask app running on a server with 2 CPUs and 2GB of RAM.
The application is configured with Gunicorn and has 3 workers.
As far as I know, it means my app can handle 3 concurrent requests.

Therefore, I wonder:

1. If I use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() and open a new thread when running a task and NOT waiting for its completion - Would the worker be able to handle additional concurrent requests?
2. If I use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() and open a new thread when running a task and WAIT for its completion, like this:

```py
# Create a ThreadPoolExecutor
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

# Submit a task to the executor
future = executor.submit(api_request)

# Wait for the future to finish
response = future.result()
```

Does it have any effect? Would the worker be able to handle additional concurrent requests? Or I do not need to use a new thread in this case?